# Using List comprehension for recursive function

Tags: python, list, recursion, list-comprehension

I've gotten this function to work without list comprehension, however, I was wondering how to do it with one:

```
def flatten(L): 
    a_list = [] 

    for i in L: 
        if isinstance(i, list): 
            gl = flatten(i) 
            for n in gl: 
                a_list.append(n)

        else: 
            a_list.append(i) 

    return a_list 

    #  This is how I've attempted to use list comprehension, but I get a Syntax
    #  error and I'm not sure why.

    return [n for n in flatten(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in L]
```

Comment: mandatory question: what's the error?

Comment: It's a Syntax Error because he's trying to do `[n for n in flatten(i)]` but if `isinstance(i,list)` is false, do `[i for i in L]`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error can be fixed, you've got wrong precedence, you need parentheses:

```
return [(n for n in flatten(i)) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in L]
```

This, unfortunately, won't do what you would like to do and it's impossible to do with **one** list comprehension.

List comprehensions generate one result *per* input (it's like a `map` operation), so you cannot generate a list which is larger than the original, which is necessary for flattening.

Look for alternative solutions here: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Oh crap does that work? I didn't think you could use else statements to change the whole list comp, only the value! That's amazing!

Comment: Yeah, your solution adds generators to the list. However, thanks a lot  for the insight! I was skeptical whether I could do it in one comprehension. I'll try to figure out a more efficient way, if its possible.